# karate match throws an error com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Character '.' on position 3 is not valid

Tags: karate

I am trying perform match on tis json array. Scenario goes like this

```
    Scenario : match lob
    * def op = 
    """
    [
     {
      "_id": "1",
      "_class": 
          "com.xxx.versionone.tir.enterprise.persistence.model.xxx",
      "lobName": "abc",
      "changeDate": "2016-11-04T11:41:40",
      "changedBy": "abc",
      "createdDate": "2014-07-01T11:47:23",
      "lastSdpPublishDate": "2018-10-31T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
           "$oid": "57883a41e4b076d23a82e9e7"
           },
     "_class": 
  "com.xxx.versionone.tir.enterprise.persistence.model.xxx",
    "lobName": "asda",
    "changeDate": "2016-07-14T21:20:54",
     "changedBy": "TXA858",
     "createdDate": "2016-07-14T21:20:01",
     "createdBy": "TXA858",
     "lastSdpPublishDate": "2018-10-31T00:00:00"
     }
    ]
"""
* match $op...lobName contains ["abc"]
```

I get this error:
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Character '.' on position 3 is not valid.
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
  at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchContains(StepDefs.java:532)

Comment: Oh, I figured it out but not entirely. See this                                                                      
     ```* print karate.pretty(op[*].lobName)```  prints nothing.Why is this not printing anything?
But this mtach worked (used [*])
   ``` * match $op[*].lobName contains ["abc"]```.

Comment: My asterick is converted to some strange symbol in above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON path deep scan is `..` **not** `...`

This should work,

```
* match $op..lobName contains ["abc"]
```

[Json path operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying different things. The thing that is confusing is ``` * print $op..lobName``` prints nothing.

Comment: @Kumar112 you can't use JsonPath wherever you want just like JS. Please be clear about the difference between `op[0].lobName` and `$op[*].lobName`, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Comment: @PeterThomas Any idea why the print is not printing anything? ``` * print $op..lobName``` or ```* print op..lobName``` ?

Comment: @kumar112 try * def lobNames = karate.jsonPath(op, $..lobName) * print lobNames

Comment: @Kumar112 because `print` expects *pure JS* after it

Comment: ok, this worked.    * def lobNames = karate.jsonPath(op, "$..lobName")
    * print lobNames